# Is there a way to write this list comprehension faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, list-comprehension

I am writing some high-performance code and my current bottleneck (>50% run time) is around creating a list that fits certain parameters as fast as possible. Currently, I am using list-comprehension to do this, but I am wondering if there is a more optimal approach.

This is in python3.6. I already have a subset of code which runs in cython and a subset of code which runs with numba jit. This is the interface between my python code and these pieces of compiled code. The list that is created is then passed to cython and numba functions to do the heavy mathematics. I have already tried not including the constrains in the list comprehension (e.g. `max_x > bead.x > min_x`). However, this makes the list so large that it slows the overall speed of the program. Extra detail: max_, bead. and min_ variables are all floats and there are around 600 entires of bead in chromosome. Once the list is created and used as an input to the cython function it is no longer used again, and a new f list is created on the next call of this section of code (with different max_ and min_ values). For clarity self.chromosome is a list of chromosome objects which can be iterated through to get bead objects. Bead objects have parameters of interest that are needed for the list creation.

```py
for chromosome in self.chromosomes: 
            if chromosome != move.chromosome:
                f = [[bead.x, bead.y, bead.z, bead.radius] for bead in 
                      chromosome if max_x > bead.x > min_x and max_y > 
                      bead.y > min_y and max_z > bead.z > min_z]
# do cython stuff with f
```

If there are any ideas on how to speed this list-making that would be fantastic. I want to try and avoid pushing too much of my code into cython where possible to preserve readability.

Comment: Taking the list comprehension on its own; no, I don't think so. It looks like you have a class here holding your data. I have zero idea here what you are actually in control of, but if you abstract away the class to a 2D numpy array as early on as possible, then you could be doing this in a vectorized manner; that would drop jitting and Cython to a large degree, but also obscures the code at the same time. Python is not a performance language so at some point you're going to hit a trade-off

Comment: I don't see any possible improvement regarding the speed.

Comment: How many calls using different min/max are you making? I ask because the higher that is the more benefit we'd expect from preprocessing the list.

Comment: @TemporalWolf at least one call for every iteration of the code. Total is around 2 million times for the total run of the program. Every time is called it should have a different min and max. Furthermore, bead.x,y,z will change everytime it is called, as each iteration will make changes to these. So I can't really reuse the lists.

Comment: Does the order of the beads in the chromosome matter?

Comment: The reason is there may be a speed up associated with maintaining x,y,z ordering lists. Then, instead of iterating through every bead, take the set intersection of `(x[min:max], y[min:max], z[min:max])` will give you every bead which should be in `f`. Depending on the percentage of beads applicable in every iteration, this could outperform the added overhead.

Comment: @TemporalWolf that seems a good idea. Technically the bead order does not matter as in each bead object has bead.id. So I would need to have 3 additional lists which are kept in order? I will have to try this out, as I will have some additional processing of removing and adding values to these lists when the x,y,z change for beads every iteration. I will post back the results.

Comment: Depending on the requirements downstream you may gain something by using `tuple`s instead of `list`s. At least on my machine constructing a tuple is twice as fast as constructing a list. Compare `python -m timeit -s "x,y,z=3,14,1592" '(x,y,z)'` vs `python -m timeit -s "x,y,z=3,14,1592" '[x,y,z]'`

Comment: Ultimately if performance is an issue switching to a faster language would likely give the most speed up: we sped up some graph analysis code of ours around 10,000x by switching from python to [bit twiddling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation) c. What previously took days to run took less than a minute.

Comment: I would recommend not creating a bunch of list objects or even operating on python objects in general in a tight inner loop like that. If possible, you should try to make your function operation on C arrays or cython typed-memoryviews of data instead. For example, instead of using a class to model the `Bead` objects of a chromosome, you could use a `cdef struct Bead` instead.